# How to implement a donations system with google wallet for a non profit organization?

Tags: android-pay, donations

I am developing a website with a donations system. And one of the requirements is to use Google Wallet. I would like to know if there is documentation about how to use a donation button with Google Wallet?

http://www.google.com/nonprofits/onlinebasics/

Most of the information I have found is related to purchasing, but not donations. I would appreciate it if you can send me a link with Google documentation on how to integrate donations via Google Wallet in a website. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i read over the internet Google Wallet does provide donation system for a non-profit organizations. It's enough to sign up for a Google merchant account, which will require you to tell Google about your nonprofit and its business structure. Hope this [article](http://www.nonprofithub.org/nonprofit-technology/use-google-wallet-to-make-donations-easy/) is helpful.